# Eigenvalues of a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Sturm-Liouville problem

$$-u''(x) + V(x)u(x) = \lambda u(x)$$

for $u : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. I am looking for a method to find the eigenvalues $\lambda$ which produce solutions $u \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ for various choices of $V$, e.g. $V(x) = c/\cosh^2(Cx)$ or $V(x) = e^x$. Is there a general procedure for doing this? If not, can someone provide suggestions for finding the eigenvalues at least in the two cases I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, there is such a procedure. I recall having read something related to this in the classical book on ordinary differential equations by Coddington and Levinson. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/137468/8157).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerically the problem can be solved e.g. using the [Numerov algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) with the [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method). There are only a few choices for $V$ for which there is an explicit analytic solution, some of them you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions).

One of it is $$V(x) = \frac{c}{\cosh^2(C x)}$$ which is called the [Pöschl–Teller potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential). However, it only has solutions in $L^2$ if $c<0$. After proper rescaling, you will find that the eigensolutions solutions are Legendre functions.

When $V(x) =e^{x}$ I believe that the eigenvalue problem does not have any solution in $L^2$.

Comment: Nice!  I wasn't familiar with the Ploeschl-Teller potential.

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues $\lambda$ emerge from boundary conditions that are part of the differential operator.  In your case, $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$, so you may specify the behavior of $u$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  One way to attack this is to consider the Fourier transform of $u$:

$$ \hat{u}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: u(x) \exp{(i 2 \pi k x)} $$

Applying the integral operator to the S-L equation, and integrating by parts (and assuming that $u$ and its derivative vanish at $\infty$), we get an integral equation for $ \hat{u}$:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk' \: \hat{V}(k-k') \hat{u}(k') = (\lambda + 4 \pi^2 k^2) \hat{u}(k)  $$

where

$$ \hat{V}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: V(x) \exp{(i 2 \pi k x)} $$

and we recover the solution from

$$ u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \hat{u}(k) \exp{(-i 2 \pi k x)} $$

Comment: How does one solve the integral equation you get after applying the fourier transform?

Comment: You can approximate the convolution by a matrix product. Be warned, however, that the functions $V$ must be $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Can it be solved explicitly for the choices of $V$ I mentioned in the original post?

Comment: The first, yes, the second, no.  But with the second (or anything that is not $L^2(\mathbb{R})$), no technique will work.  For those functions, you need to work over a finite interval; in such cases, other techniques may be more appropriate.

Comment: How would I go about solving it for $V(x) = c/\cosh^2(cx)$?

Comment: As I do not have a lot of time and access to my Mathematica right now, I can only tell you to construct the matrix $\hat{V}$ from values of the Fourier transform of $c/\cosh^2{C x}$ (proportional to $k/\sinh{k}$).  You want to construct a band diagonal matrix, as the kernel function $V$ only depends on the difference between the matrix indices, the integral being a convolution.  Your unknowns are the sample values of $\hat{u}$ corresponding to the values of $V$.  I know this isn't the clearest, but look for numerical techniques for solving integral equations of Fredholm type for more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique called "AIM" which stands for "asymptotic iteration method". See for instance this [reference 1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0412030v1.pdf) and [reference 2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2467v1.pdf).